# How to get the value of clicked slice in Amcharts 4 pie chart

Tags: javascript, pie-chart, amcharts4

I am trying to get the value of clicked slice in Amcharts 4 3d pie chart. I am using this below code:

```
<!-- Styles -->
<style>
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

</style>

<!-- Resources -->
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<!-- Chart code -->
<script>
am4core.ready(function() {

// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.PieChart3D);
chart.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 0; // this creates initial fade-in

chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();

chart.data = [
  {
    country: "Lithuania",
    litres: 501.9
  },
  {
    country: "Czech Republic",
    litres: 301.9
  },
  {
    country: "Ireland",
    litres: 201.1
  },
  {
    country: "Germany",
    litres: 165.8
  },
  {
    country: "Australia",
    litres: 139.9
  },
  {
    country: "Austria",
    litres: 128.3
  },
  {
    country: "UK",
    litres: 99
  },
  {
    country: "Belgium",
    litres: 60
  },
  {
    country: "The Netherlands",
    litres: 50
  }
];

var pieSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries3D());
pieSeries.dataFields.value = "litres";
pieSeries.dataFields.category = "country";

// AMCHART OFFICIAL DOCUMENTATION: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/one-pulled-slice-per-pie-chart/#Solution
pieSeries.slices.template.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
  var series = ev.target.dataItem.component;
  console.log(series);
});

}); // end am4core.ready()
</script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
amCharts
```

Now, as per Amcharts official documentation I added the `hit` event. Neither I know how to get the value of the clicked slice nor I found any documentation/post regarding it.

Now, there are a couple of stackoverflow posts about the same but for Amcharts version 3 library and I am particularly looking for Amchart's version 4 library.

Kindly guide me here on how to get the value of clicked slice in Amcharts version 4 library.

**Update**: I am looking forward to get the property of `country` of `chart.data`.

Comment: By value you mean the `litres` property of `chart.data` of the clicked slice?

Comment: @Lain, yeah. Actually, I wanted the `country` property of `chart.data` of the clicked slice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually shows in the link you provided. It is merely a bit burried. To get the assigned `value` property of the clicked slice, you can access the `dataItem.value` of the current element `ev.target`:

```
//AMCHART OFFICIAL DOCUMENTATION: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/one-pulled-slice-per-pie-chart/#Solution
pieSeries.slices.template.events.on("hit", function(ev){
  console.log(ev.target.dataItem.value)
});
```

Comment: Hey @Lain, your code worked. But sorry my mistake. Actually, I wanted the `country` property of `chart.data` of the clicked slice.

Comment: Hey, but using `ev.target.dataItem.category`, I got what I wanted. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Yes, the `country` is the `category`. It equals your implementation of the `pieSeries.dataFields`.